# Heroku case sensitivity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, search, heroku

I have recently uploaded my application to heroku and due to the postgresql, the case sensitivity does not work, I am wondering how will I fix this? My code is as followed:

```
relation = Game.gamsearch(params[:gamsearch])
relation = Game.consearch(params[:consearch]) if params[:consearch].present? 
relation = Game.gensearch(params[:gensearch]) if params[:gensearch].present? 
relation = Game.where("game_name LIKE ?", "#{params[:game_name]}%") if params[:game_name].present? 
relation = Game.where("console = ?", params[:console]) if params[:console].present?
```

view code:

```
<%= form_tag games_path, :controller => 'games', :action => 'gamsearch', :method => 'get' do %>
                        <%= text_field_tag :gamsearch, params[:gamsearch] %>
                        <%= submit_tag t('.searchb'), :game_name => nil %>
                        <% end %>
```

This is the model code:

```
def self.gensearch(*args)
#search for games by their genre
return [] if args.blank?
cond_text, cond_values = [], []
args.each do |str|
  next if str.blank?
  cond_text << "( %s )" % str.split.map{|w| "genre LIKE ? "}.join(" OR ")
  cond_values.concat(str.split.map{|w| "%#{w}%"})
end
all :conditions =>  [cond_text.join(" AND "), *cond_values]
```

end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
relation = Game.where("game_name ILIKE ?", "#{params[:game_name]}%") if params[:game_name].present?
```

notice the ILIKE instead of LIKE

Comment: That's great. How would I do it for the other searches, particularly the first one on the list or is this beyond your knowledge

Comment: You'd need to use ILIKE inside the gamsearch method, same for consearch and gensearch. Without seeing those methods it is beyond my knowledge :)

Comment: that's view code. I would need to see the contents of models/game.rb

Answer (score 2):

ILIKE is the way to go for PG, but if you have another database (sqlite) in development, that might not work. One way to get around this is to make both values uppercase and then compare the uppercased version of both.

Comment: yep, valid point. However I would always maintain that you should be building against the DB that you're intending to  deploy to.

Comment: Of course! But to some, PG in dev is a bit overkill! They probably should switch to mongo, but that's another topic ;-)